# Add a single column to multiple SHP

Tags: qgis, shapefile, r

I was looking for a way to add a new column to several shp (simple polygons) at the same time. I don't know much about batch command.

This new attribute is also a little bit tricky : I need to generate new datas which will be a classification based on the standard deviation from an existing column.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not at all clear. I am assuming that you want to operate on multiple shapefiles and not just the contents of a single shapefile.

In R you can write a for loop for reading, modifying and writing shapefiles. Here is an example where I read each shapefile, apply an ifelse statement to classify a defined field and write the results. I am using the rgdal package for reading/writing the shapefiles. Since I am using example data I am adding a step in the for loop where I add a dummy variable to classify.

You may notice that I wrote a "y.class" function that classifies the "y.name" column and pass it to the for loop. If you are applying a standard process across datasets, it is good practice to write a function.

```
require(rgdal)
require(sp)

# Creath path and vector of shapefiles in directory
spath <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
  ( shps <- list.files(spath, ".shp$") )

# variable for attribute column name
y.name = "y"  

# Function to classify column based on quantiles using ifelse 
y.class <- function(y) {
  p <- summary( y )[c(2,3,5)] 
    ifelse( y < p[1], 1,
      ifelse( y >= p[1] & y <= p[2], 2,
        ifelse( y > p[2], 3, NA) ) )
}  

# for loop for reading modifying and writing shapefiles
for(i in length(shps)) {  
  s <- readOGR(spath, strsplit(shps[1], "[.]")[[1]][1] )
    # add dummy column
    s@data <- data.frame(s@data, y=runif(nrow(s),0,1))

    # Apply y.class function on y.name column   
    s@data <- data.frame(s@data, class=y.class(s@data[,y.name]) )

    # Overwrite shapefile with resulting classified column added                          
    writeOGR(s, dsn=getwd(), strsplit(shps[1], "[.]")[[1]][1],
             driver="ESRI Shapefile", check_exists=TRUE,  
             overwrite_layer=TRUE)  
}
```

In the for loop I create and add a dummy variable "y" and then classify it using quartiles in an ifelse statement. I define the name of the column with the variable "y.name". This allows one to set a common column name, that will be operated on, across shapefiles. Please note that sp spatial objects store the attribute table in a slot that can be accessed via @data.